# dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, scaffold

I'm trying to use dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold on macbook M1, but I got error:

Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.11/libhostpolicy.dylib, error: dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.11/libhostpolicy.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.11/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file)
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.dylib from [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.11]

This happens after updating to .NET6, but the current project is still .NET5. The project is building and working successfully, the problem only occurs when scaffolding changes from database

Comment: You have to make sure the installed SDKs are the arm64 version. By reading the error, it seems that you have the x64 version of the .NET 5 SDK installed.

Comment: I'm getting this error after I updated to .NET 6. Prevously everything was working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else, I was experiencing the same issue and I seemed to have had some old versions of dotnet lingering around.

```
$ dotnet-ef
Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.14/libhostpolicy.dylib, error: dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.14/libhostpolicy.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.14/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file)
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.dylib from [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.14]


$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.407 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

$ dotnet tool list --global
Package Id      Version      Commands 
--------------------------------------
dotnet-ef       6.0.1        dotnet-ef
```

I resolved by completely removing and reinstalling dotnet via home-brew.

```
$ brew uninstall dotnet-sdk

...

$ ls -la /usr/local/share/   
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   64 17 Jan 14:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  288 10 Jan 15:57 ..

...

$ brew install dotnet-sdk
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
...
  dotnet-sdk was successfully installed!

$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

$ dotnet --list-sdks    
6.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]


$ dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --global
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '6.0.1') was successfully installed.

$ dotnet ef

                     _/\__       
               ---==/    \\      
         ___  ___   |.    \|\    
        | __|| __|  |  )   \\\   
        | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\ 
        |___||_|       /   \\\/\\

Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.1

Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]

Options:
  --version        Show version information
  -h|--help        Show help information
  -v|--verbose     Show verbose output.
  --no-color       Don't colorize output.
  --prefix-output  Prefix output with level.

Commands:
  database    Commands to manage the database.
  dbcontext   Commands to manage DbContext types.
  migrations  Commands to manage migrations.

Use "dotnet ef [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```